# Sending HTTP requests from a pool of IP addresses on rotation basis to avoid throttling

Tags: java, sockets, ip-address, httprequest, throttling

We want to hit a server multiple times without getting throttled. This is a basic problem now a days people face and must have found a work-around.

Long back I did a small experiment in which I assigned multiple IP Addresses to my desktop and sent HTTP requests using socket(...,...,...,..). I wrote a small servlet to test it and it was working fine.

I wanted to know if there is any better approach to perform the task.

Comment: What is the purpose of this... you intend to mimic a browser? Is this a test tool?

Comment: @EdwardH : As said, the purpose is to avoid throttling which is not done by the browser.

Comment: Why do you _need_ to avoid throttling? - and furthermore throttling by _who_?

Comment: I was trying to scrape pages by hitting keywords on Google. From time to time I found throttling issue. Because multiple request was going from the same IP/subnet mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comments, you are querying a WEB page on the internet multiple times, at high rate probably (higher than a human normal browsing rate).

As browsers, you should limit yourself to the number of connections opened simultaneously. originally, HTTP 1.1 defined 4 such connections is allowed, but latest browser versions are utilizing around 8, multiple windows of the browser add even more.
But the base rule is still there, and some server farms at big sites try to protect themselves from attacks using what you call throttling.

You can embrace the same techniques that the browsers are taking to balance request rates:

1. Limit the number of connections you open in parallel and utilize an open connection (without closing it) to send a new request when the previous one has ended.
2. A more complicated approach is to implement HTTP Pipelining, and add it to point 1 above. Pipelining allows you to send several requests on the same connection without waiting for the response, but not all sites support it (and not all browsers use it).

Your proposal to use several source address is applicable, but it depends what is the technology behind the farms that serve the site, they may assume similar IP address to originate from the same user network.

Another options is to distribute the clients over the network with different clients, which combine/sync the work through a central server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I will go into the details and see what is feasible.